# ggplot2 bar plot with two categorical variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose I have the following data:

```
Fruit <- c(rep("Apple",3),rep("Orange",5))
Bug <- c("worm","spider","spider","worm","worm","worm","worm","spider")

df <- data.frame(Fruit,Bug)
df

   Fruit    Bug
1  Apple   worm
2  Apple spider
3  Apple spider
4 Orange   worm
5 Orange   worm
6 Orange   worm
7 Orange   worm
8 Orange spider
```

I want to use ggplot to create a bar graph where we have Fruit on x axis and the fill is the bug. I want the bar plot to have counts of the bug given apple and orange. So the bar plot would look would be like this

Apple (worm(red) with y = 1,spider(blue) with y = 2)  BREAK Orange(worm(red) with y = 4, spider(blue with y = 1)

I hope that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at the examples here http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_bar.html

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
Fruit <- c(rep("Apple",3),rep("Orange",5))
Bug <- c("worm","spider","spider","worm","worm","worm","worm","spider")

df <- data.frame(Fruit,Bug)

ggplot(df, aes(Fruit, ..count..)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = Bug), position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

This is pretty easy to do with a two way table:

```
dat <- data.frame(table(df$Fruit,df$Bug))
names(dat) <- c("Fruit","Bug","Count")

ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=Fruit, y=Count, fill=Bug)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

Comment: Further, `ggplot2` actually has an option to plots counts/densities with `..count..` and `..density..` directly rather than using a two-way table.

Comment: Where is the value for `Count`?

Comment: @SabreWolfy I generate it by tabling the data `data.frame(table(df$Fruit,df$Bug))`, you can also use the built in functions like @tkmckenzie says.