# R - ggplot2 - plotting one factor by two factors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm following up on this link: [ggplot2 bar plot with two categorical variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24895575/ggplot2-bar-plot-with-two-categorical-variables)

My problem is very similar – I need to do what the OP needed but I need to split the count bars by another factor.

Let me illustrate:

```
>     var response_cat has values 0,1 (categories of a response) 
>     
>     var group indicates belonging to a group (0,1) 
>     
>     var item indicates the name of an item (20 strings with codes like LY1, GN6,...)
```

And I need to draw a graph as follows:
x axis has two bars per item (for each group)
y axis has relative frequencies of ones

any ideas?

thank you!

Comment: then you may need `facet_wrap`  Try `df %>% group_by_at(names(.)) %>% summarise(n = n()) %>% ggplot(., aes(x = Fruit, y = n, fill = Bug)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") + facet_wrap(~ group)`

Comment: Just to clarify – I'm not the OP! But thank you very much, I'm going to try it

Comment: If you are trying from that link try with `group <- rep(LETTERS[1:2], each = 4);
 df <- data.frame(Fruit,Bug, group)`

Comment: the result was a bit strange, I suppose the NAs might be at fault?: https://imgur.com/a/zygIz6u

Comment: The response_cat seems to numeric variable.

Comment: You are right. But "as.factor" doesn't seem to change it, which is weird

Comment: As you didn't provide an example, it is not clear to me.  I am suggesting from the dataset in that link

Comment: that part of the dataframe only has 0, 1 and NA, if that helps

Comment: May be try to change that `NA` to "Others" and check if that works by converting to `factor`

Comment: I solved it by re-importing the data set and forcing the "factor" and your solution works! Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `facet_wrap`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
   group_by_at(names(.)) %>%
   summarise(n = n()) %>%
   ggplot(., aes(x = Fruit, y = n, fill = Bug)) + 
   geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
   facet_wrap(~ group)
```

[image]

#### data

```
Fruit <- c(rep("Apple",3),rep("Orange",5))
Bug <- c("worm","spider","spider","worm","worm","worm","worm","spider")
group <- rep(LETTERS[1:2], each = 4)
df <- data.frame(Fruit,Bug, group)
```