# How to label plot with value of bars?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I'm trying to make a barplot with two categorical values. [This particular thread was very helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24895575/ggplot2-bar-plot-with-two-categorical-variables)

My code was this

```
ggplot(DF, aes(Participant.Type, ..count...)) + 
    geom_bar(aes(fill=Sex), position ="dodge") +
    theme_classic() +
    ggtitle("Main phenotypes stated for the PCDH19 cohort on GEL") + 
    scale_fill_viridis(option ="viridis")
```

This was my resulting graph. I'm now trying to add the count of the particular bars on top - like Female proband is 135, Male proband is 165 and so on. I tried adding different iterations of the geom_text command so I could achieve this. Commands here:

```
 + geom_text(aes(label= ..count))
 + geom_text(aes(label= Sex))
```

Could anyone please help?

[image: barplot of two categorical variables with purple for female and yellow for male]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some sample data from that question you linked you can do it like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(viridis)
#> Loading required package: viridisLite

Fruit <- c(rep("Apple", 3), rep("Orange", 5))
Bug <- c("worm", "spider", "spider", "worm", "worm", "worm", "worm", "spider")

df <- data.frame(Fruit, Bug)

ggplot(df, aes(Fruit, fill = Bug)) + geom_bar(position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = after_stat(count)),
    stat = "count",
    vjust = -0.5,
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)
  ) +
  geom_text(
    aes(y = after_stat(count), label = Bug),
    stat = "count",
    vjust = -1.5,
    position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(add = c(0, 1))) +
  scale_fill_viridis(option = "viridis", discrete = TRUE)
```

[image]

A few things to note:

- `geom_bar` doesn't need `..count..` passed as a y-value - it defaults to counting
- `after_stat(count)` is the [updated form of `..` notation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_eval.html#details)
- Text labels need dodges added - default width is 0.9 for bars so this width matches the placement of the bars.

Comment: Thank you very much, the notes are really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I can't test the process without your input data, but here's something for you to give a try:

```
+ geom_text(stat='count', aes(label=..count..), vjust=-1)
```